# Kentico Xperience Medlab sample project - view not found

Tags: kentico

I followed this sample https://docs.xperience.io/tutorial/developer-tutorial and created the MEDLAB project.

**Getting the following error**

> InvalidOperationException: The view on path '~/Views/Shared/PageTypes/MEDLAB_Home.cshtml' could not be found and there is no page template registered for selected page.
> Kentico.Content.Web.Mvc.Routing.Internal.KenticoPageBuilderPageController.Index()

The content type and the view does exist and somehow getting this error.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create the view yourself, see this part of the tutorial https://docs.xperience.io/tutorial/developer-tutorial/display-page-content#Displaypagecontent-CreatetheHomeview

Comment: Thank you, for you response. I did create the view.